# Google Maps API v3 generating lines dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am working on a Google Maps prototype and I would like to draw a line connecting each of the markers on my map. However, currently I am hardcoding the coordinates for the line separate from the coordinates used for the markers and was wondering how I can make it dynamic so that I only have to add markers and the line will automatically be generated from those points.

The portion of the script I want to be generated dynamically is commented

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Travel Log</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var locations = [
        ['Mankato, MN', 44.1834814, -93.9774519, 1],
        ['Duluth, MN', 46.7649885, -92.1112232, 2],
        ['Rochester, MN', 43.9959876, -92.4811724, 3],
        ['Fargo, ND', 46.8541979, -96.8285138, 4],
        ['Minneapolis, MN', 44.970697, -93.2614785, 5]
      ];
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.4418595,-93.3655146)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////
        //This is the part I want to be dynamic//
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        var lineCoordinates = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(44.1834814, -93.9774519),
          new google.maps.LatLng(46.7649885, -92.1112232),
          new google.maps.LatLng(43.9959876, -92.4811724),
          new google.maps.LatLng(46.8541979, -96.8285138),
          new google.maps.LatLng(44.970697, -93.2614785)
        ];

        var tripPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: lineCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        tripPath.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3x4qcnk/)

Comment: fill `lineCoordinates` inside the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/r3x4qcnk/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using the [`Array.prototype.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) quite nicely;

```
var lineCoordinates = locations.map(function (val) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(val[1], val[2]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3x4qcnk/1/